# Android draws a gray view bar on right side of the screen on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

Inside my android app, all activites give me a strange thick gray bar on the right side after orientation change from Landscape to portrait. A similar gray bar appears at the bottom of the screen for all activites in landscape mode. At first I thought the gray bar was due to a view from my layout.
But after looking at the view hierarchy from the UI automator in Android Device Monitor, I found that it is a nameless `View` object. Here are the screenshots for ADM along with my view hierarchy:

[The screenshot of the app which shows the gray strip on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GqmD.png)

[Here is the view hierarchy of the view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBZFT.png)

As you can see the gray strip is an object of `View` and does not seem to have any `resource-id` like other views.
I would like to know the source of this gray bar view in my source code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post your source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to solve the problem and trying to track the issue, I finally managed to solve it. It turns out that the issue was caused in Android Lollipop and above versions due to the following code which had `setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true)`. Commenting that line solved the problem.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = ((Activity) context).getWindow();


                SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(((Activity) context));
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
                //tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);
             //tintManager.setNavigationBarTintColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tintManager.setTintColor(Color.parseColor("#" + appVO.getStatusbarColor()));
                //  tintManager.setTintColor(((Activity) context).getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                float f = Float.parseFloat(".7");
                tintManager.setTintAlpha(f);
                // tintManager.setTintAlpha(f);
```